# How would I know if an AWS key with S3 access got into the wrong hands?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We are assigning IAM access keys with only S3 access.

What would I have to do to make sure there are not 1000 unique IPs making downloads to S3 from the S3 key?

I want to be alerted if someone loses an s3 key and a hacker recursively downloads all files in our s3.

Comment: So you want to restrict the number of concurrent requests?

Comment: I want to be alerted if someone loses an s3 key and a hacker recursively downloads all files in our s3.

Comment: More information is needed.  Who are you giving these keys to, and for what specific purpose?

Comment: Keys are given to multiple developers to access a centralized dataset. How would I detect if one of these devs gets hacked and loses their IAM keys for s3 access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no in-built mechanism to give you such a warning. However, here are some options to consider...

You could **restrict access to a specific range of IP addresses** (eg, a corporate network) so that the Amazon S3 bucket can only be accessed from those IP addresses. This is highly recommended if you know they will only be accessed from certain IP addresses.

You could **monitor the [Amazon S3 bucket logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html)**, which record each access to Amazon S3 objects. These logs could be passed to **Amazon CloudWatch Events**, which could be configured to count the number of times objects are being accessed. You could then create an Amazon CloudWatch Alarm to send a notification if the count of accesses exceeds a certain threshold.

You could use Amazon CloudTrail to track [object-level operations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/log-s3-data-events.html) and pass them to Amazon CloudWatch Events (similar to the above).

You could use **temporary credentials instead of permanent credentials**. Rather than giving people credentials that last forever, you could have them authenticate against a system that then provides time-limited credentials using the [AWS Security Token Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html). These credentials automatically expire after a specific period of time. This way, if credentials get 'into the wild', they will only be valid for a specific period of time, after which they cannot be used.